# Matlab getting distance of vector and a matrix

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to get the euclidean distance from a vector and a matrix

```
dataTest= [1;2;3;4;5;6]

data = [01 02 03 04;
       05 06 07 08;
       09 10 11 12; 
       13 14 15 16;
       17 18 19 20;
       21 22 23 24]
```

Currently when I run this function: 
`distance = pdist2(data ,dataTest)` it returns

> X and Y must have the same number of columns.

Any suggestions how i could fix this and possibly why mine isn't working?

EDIT: Fixed it - Did not fill up the entire dataTest matrix - had to iterate through every column.

Comment: **Don't iterate**, use `repmat` instead. Iterating in Matlab is **very** slow

Comment: Is `distance = pdist2(data.', dataTest.')` what you want? Note that `pdist2` considers each _row_ in the input matrices to be a point in Euclidean space

Answer (score 0):

As @Luis mentioned, `pdist2` will give you much more information, and calculations that you don't need because it computes all the distances, and you actually need just the diagonal of the matrix result from each iteration.

Instead, you can just compute exactly what you need- the euclidean distance between the vector `dataTest` and each of the columns of `data`:

```
  distance= sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,dataTest,data).^2))

  distance=
  22.2486 24.3105 26.4386 28.6182
```